# Xschem and ngspice Error: unknown subckt

Tags: ngspice

I'm trying to get started with xschem and ngspice to simulate some circuits but have problems getting the programs installed.

I tried a very small circuit with 1 transistor, but get an error. After looking around on the web I still don't now how to fix it.
In the manual I found that there should be external port names in the line of the .subckt but xschem doens't generated this, can that be a problem?
I don't now if I need to add something extra in the schematic?

I will add picture of schematic, netlis and simulation error below.

Thanks in advance!
I'm very new to this, so it is very possible it is a very stupid mistake.
Kind Regards
Faith

[image: the error message]
[image: the schematic]
[image: The netlist generated by xschem]

Comment: Looks like you need the `.LIB` file for the IRF540, and then add a `.lib sihf540.lib` as a SPICE command on the schematic .  The file is available on Vishay's site here:  https://www.vishay.com/mosfets/list/product-91021/tab/designtools-ppg/

Comment: Super! Thank you! That fixed it! Thank you !